# How can I change the text "learn more" in video preroll

Tags: ios, google-ima

I m using google-ima SDK for iOS version 3.0.beta.4.

I try to change the text "Learn more" which appear at the sdk's `UIViewController`.

I'm looking for that for some time, and didn't find the answer.

Does someone achieve it?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the language:

```
    let s = IMASettings()
    s.language = "it"
    adsLoader = IMAAdsLoader.init(settings: s)
    adsLoader?.delegate = self
```